# Place auto complete is not working after updating to version 3.0.2 - Google iOS sdk

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I had the implementation of place auto completion using `GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController` was working fine so far. But when I updated the sdk to 3.0.2 stopped working. If I revert to version 2.7.0 start working.

I have gone through the [migrationguide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/releases) not getting what I am missing. I checked the [examples](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete) didn't observe any changes. Would anyone point me in the right direction to make it work again?

```
class PlaceAutoCompleteController: BaseViewController {

    //MARK: - Property declaration
    private var resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    private lazy var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    private var viewModel: PlaceTypeAheadViewModel
    var storeSelectionDelegate: StoreSelectionDelegate?

    //MARK: - Life cycle
    init(withViewModel aviewModel: PlaceTypeAheadViewModel) {
        viewModel = aviewModel
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupProperties()
    }
}

//MARK: - Property setup
extension PlaceAutoCompleteController {

    /// Setting up view default properties
    func setupProperties() {

        resultsViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        resultsViewController.tableCellBackgroundColor = .white
        resultsViewController.delegate = self

        // Specify the place data types to return.
//        let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
//            UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))!
//        resultsViewController.placeFields = fields

        let filter      = GMSAutocompleteFilter()

        //suitable filter type
        filter.type     = .establishment
        filter.country  = viewModel.getCountryId()
        resultsViewController.autocompleteFilter = filter

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        // Put the search bar in the navigation bar.
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search places"
        let searchBgView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))
        searchBgView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
        view.addSubview(searchBgView)

        // Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        // This makes the view area include the nav bar even though it is opaque.
        // Adjust the view placement down.
        extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []

    }
}

// Handle the user's selection.
extension PlaceAutoCompleteController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        searchController.isActive = false
        AppManager.setPlace(withPlaceId: place.placeID ?? "" , name: place.name ?? "" , latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        openStoreSelection()
    }

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    /// Open store selection screen with selected country
    func openStoreSelection() {
        navigateToStoreSelection()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it showing any particular error message?

Comment: @shivi_shub:  No. ```didRequestAutocompletePredictions```  and ```didUpdateAutocompletePredictions``` these delegates are not event getting called. 
But I am setting  ```resultsViewController.delegate = self```.

Comment: post your code in question

Comment: @JaydeepVyas:  I have added the code.

Comment: @Alex change your method with updated methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the access from business people, accepted the privacy policy and I couldn't find the appkey in credentials which they have shared earlier.
Now I started using iOS key (auto created by Google Service) which working perfectly fine with updated sdk version i.e 3.0.3

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your Google Cloud project:

1. Make sure you enabled "Places API". The old one "Places SDK for iOS" does not work with 3.0.0 version of SDK.

[image]

2. Update API restrictions for your API key with "Places API" instead of "Places SDK for iOS"

[image]

3. Setup billing details for your Google Cloud project